# Python unittest ends with failure

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I run the following unit test in python, the result should be correct, but the unit test goes wrong.

What is the mistake?

This is the Class I have to test

```
class Strategy:
    _a = 0
    _b = 0
    _result = 0

    def __init__(self, a, b):

        try:
            int(a)
            int(b)
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError()

        self._a = a
        self._b = b
```

This is my unittest

```
def test_invalideValue(self):
    with self.assertRaises(ValueError) as cm:
        StrategyAddition('A', 3)

    self.assertEqual(cm.exception, ValueError())
```

and this the put

```
Failure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Michi\workspace_python\DesignPatternPython\Strategy\TestStrategy.py", line 24, in test_invalideValue
    self.assertEqual(cm.exception, ValueError())
AssertionError: ValueError() != ValueError()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Exception` objects do not implement custom equality tests, and without a `__eq__` method only *identity tests* are going to be true:

```
>>> a = ValueError()
>>> a == a
True
>>> a == ValueError()
False
```

You don't need to test for equality **at all**, as `self.assertRaises` would only catch a `ValueError` instance *anyway*.

If you did have a different reason to test for the exception being a `ValueError`, use `isinstance()` instead:

```
self.assertTrue(isinstance(cm.exception, ValueError))
```

Otherwise, `cm.exception` is only there to test *other* aspects of the exception, like specific attributes.